# Set up DirSync, then had to build new domain. How do I fix AD/O365 syncing?

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365

I set up DirSync for an all-new environment, and about a week after setting it up, I had to take out the old DC and stand up a new one from scratch with a new domain name, etc. Obviously that broke the synchronization between AD and Office 365.

How do I associate DirSync with the new domain and resume syncing?

We haven't deployed the new AD or O365 environment yet so if I need to nuke something on the O365/DirSync side and start over that's fine, just need specific instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you rerun the Dirsync setup wizard that should get things going again for you. I forget if it's available from the Start Menu or if you'll need to browse to the install folder (C:\Program Files\Azure Active Directory Sync...) and run it from there, though.

Comment: I re-ran the configuration tool from the Start menu and it showed that it worked. But I created a user in AD, opened Synchronization Service Manager and forced a sync, and it doesn't pull the new object up to O365.

Comment: Also, the DirSync logs show "completed-discovery-errors" on Full Import Full Sync and "completed-sync-errors" on Delta Import Delta Sync.

Comment: Without seeing the specific errors it's hard to say what's going on. You might just uninstall it and reinstall with a fresh database.